# match object between three files and multiplicate the scores associated with by perl

Tags: perl

my purpose is to compare the ID pairs that are in three files. Each ID pair is associated with a value. If I find the same ID pair in two files I want to moltiplicate the related values and print the ID pair and the final score. I want the same if the ID pair is found in all the three files. Otherwise (for "singles ID pairs", found only in one file) I want to print the ID pair and the value. A particular point is related to the order of the IDs in each pair. The ID order of each pair can differ from file to file and I need to keep this in mind while comparing
ID pairs.
My files look like this:

```
ros.txt
a|b 1
d|c 2
f|t 3
g|i 4

exp.txt
a|b 1
c|d 2
e|f 3
g|h 4

phy.txt
b|a 1
d|c 2
f|e 3
g|p 4
```

What I did so far is this:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    my %rosetta;
    open (my $ROS, '<', 'ros.txt') or die "$!";
    while (<$ROS>) {
    my ($tmp_r,$vr)=split/\t/;
    next if $vr =~/NA/;
    my ($r1,$r2)=split/\|/,$tmp_r;
    next if $r1 eq $r2;

    my %expression;
    open (my $EX, '<', 'exp.txt') or die "$!";
    while (<$EX>) {
    my ($tmp_e,$ve)=split/ /;
    next if $ve =~/NA/;
    my ($e1,$e2)=split/\|/,$tmp_e;
    next if $e1 eq $e2;

    my %phyloge;    
    open (my $PHY, '<', 'phy.txt') or die "$!"_;
    while (<$PHY>) {
    my ($tmp_p,$vp)=split/ /;
    next if $vp =~/NA/;
    my($p1,$p2)=split/\|/,$tmp_p;
    next if $p1 eq $p2;     
    }
    }
    }
```

At this point I'm not able to go on and I need some suggestion to solve my problem.
My desired output is:

```
a|b 1
c|d 8
f|t 3
e|f 9
g|h 4
g|i 4
g|p 4
```

waiting for help! Thank you in advance

Comment: You likely need to use a hash structure but that will make it difficult to display the results in the order the values are received (hash structs are stored unordered). Do you need the values stored in the order they are received from the data files or do you just need to present an ordered (sorted) output regardless of the order the data is received? The files have data arranged in ascending order, so it is not clear if you need to be able to handle data in an unordered format but output in an ordered format. 

A bit more info would help decide what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $data   = {};
my $result = {};
my @files  = qw( ros.txt exp.txt phy.txt );

foreach my $file ( @files )
{
    open FILE, '<', $file or die "$!";
    while( <FILE> )
    {
        if( /^(\w)\|(\w) (NA|\d+)$/ )
        {
            if( $3 ne 'NA' )
            {
                my @pair = ($1,$2);
                $data->{ $file }->{ join( '|', sort( @pair ) ) } = $3;
            }
        }
    }
    close FILE;
}

foreach my $file ( @files )
{
    my $curr_file = $data->{ $file };
    delete $data->{ $file };

    foreach my $pair ( keys %$curr_file )
    {
        $result->{ $pair } = $curr_file->{ $pair };

        foreach my $other_file ( @files )
        {                
            my $val = $data->{ $other_file }->{ $pair };
            if( defined $val )
            {
                $result->{ $pair } *= $val;
                delete $data->{ $other_file }->{ $pair };
            }
        }            
    } 
}

print "$_ $result->{ $_ }\n" foreach sort keys %$result;
```

Answer (score 2):

- split every line into `@F` array by `\s` or `|`.
- multiply `$F[2]` by previous value of first two elements (sorted `@F[0,1]`)

---

```
perl -F'[\s\|]' -lane'
  $k = join "|", sort @F[0,1];
  $s{$k} = ($s{$k}||1) * $F[2];
  END {
    print "$_ $s{$_}" for sort keys %s;
  }
' ros.txt exp.txt phy.txt
```

output

```
a|b 1
c|d 8
e|f 9
f|t 3
g|h 4
g|i 4
g|p 4
```

Comment: that's awesome. I was trying using `awk` and this syntax looks similar. I am only aware of `Perl` scripting files. Can you please point me to document/reference for perl one liner syntax? Also I could not find description of `-lane` in `man perl`. Thanks.

Comment: @jkshah check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html In adition you can use `-MO=Deparse` option to see full source behind command line switches.

Comment: Just a small note: `${$k}||1` means that no ID pair is allowed to have a value of zero. If you want to allow zero use `${$k}//1` instead.

Comment: @mpapec no, your answer is fine and your code also. The only problem is that, trying the code on large files in which the value in each row looks like 0.362 (each value is with three or four decimal places) I get an ambiguous result. May you suggest something?

Comment: @Gabelins can you provide such examples? Perhaps by posting another question as it seems that issue are very small numbers?